# SpringBoot HandlerInterceptor not intercepting library endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a SpringBoot app where I have implemented a HandlerInterceptor to log general information about API usage. I want it to also log requests to [Spring Security's OAuth2 endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.html) but it does not intercept the request.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

    // register the interceptor that will write API usage info to a file
    registry.addInterceptor(new ServiceUsageInterceptor());
}
```

How can I configure the HandlerInterceptor to intercept all requests?

Thanks

Comment: Show your intercepter class also.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be unrelated to the interceptor. The usage was being written to a log file using a custom AccessLogValve in the embedded Tomcat. Updating the pattern seemed to resolve the issue.

```
@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
        CustomAccessLogValve accessLogValve = new CustomAccessLogValve();
        accessLogValve.setEnabled(true);

        // set pattern
        accessLogValve.setPattern("timestamp=\"%t\" local_host=\"%v\" status=\"%s\" remote_host=\"%h\" client_id=\"%q\" uri=\"%r\" execution_time=\"%D\"");

        factory.addContextValves(accessLogValve);
    }
}
```